# null文字判定と置き換え

Tags: perl

読み込んだCSVファイルから、nullをスペースに置き換えて出力したいです。

nullは,,のところです。
1レコード17項目です。

読み込みファイル
01,,01,4ｶﾅ-0001,５漢字－０００１,６,７年月-0001,８日付-0001,９－０００１,１０ー０００１,１１ー０００１,１２ー０００１,3,4,１５ー０００１,6,17000001
02,0002,,4ｶﾅ-0002,５漢字－０００2,６,７年月-0002,８日付-0002,９－０００2ｅ,１０ー０００２,１１ー０００２,１２ー０００２,3,4,１５ー０００２,6,17000002

出力
＊△は半角スペース
01,△△△△,01,4ｶﾅ-0001,５漢字－０００１,６,７年月-0001,８日付-0001,９－０００１,１０ー０００１,１１ー０００１,１２ー０００１,3,4,１５ー０００１,6,17000001
02,0002,△△,4ｶﾅ-0002,５漢字－０００２,６,７年月-0002,８日付-0002,９内容－０００2,１０ー０００２,１１ー０００２,１２ー０００２,3,4,１５ー０００２,6,17000002

```
        open IN2, "<:encoding(utf8)", "$input_FILE" or die;
        open OUT2, ">:encoding(utf8)", "$output_FILE" or die;

        while ( my $line2 = <IN2>) {
            # 改行を削除
            chomp $line2;

            # レコード前後の""を外す
            $line2 =~ s/^"//;
            $line2 =~ s/"$//;

            # 1レコード項目ごとに分割
            my @data2 = split(/,/, $line2);

            # レコードにnullが含まれている？
            if ( $line2 =~ undef ) {
                $line2 =~ s/$line2/ /g;
                print "nullがあったよ!\n";
            } else {
                print "nullないよ！\n";
            }

            print OUT2 join (",", @data2),"\n";

        }
        close IN2;
        close OUT2;
```

undefのところを\0にしても反応がありませんでしたが、undefは反応し、ディスプレイに表示もされましたが、出力ファイルにスペースが出力されておらず、判定のみで置き換えができていませんでした。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 本題で無いのでコメントにしておきますが、Text::CSV_XSのようなCSVパーサ/ビルダを使った方がよいです。`split /,/`での分割はデータ中にカンマや改行を含む文字列があると破綻します

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perlでnull文字は`\0`か`\x00`を使います。

```
open IN2, "<:encoding(utf8)", "$input_FILE" or die;
open OUT2, ">:encoding(utf8)", "$output_FILE" or die;

while (my $line2 = <IN2>) {
    # null文字列が存在する？
    if ($line2 =~ s/\x00/ /g) {
        print "nullがあったよ\n";
    } else {
        print "nullがないよ\n";
    }
    print OUT2 $line2;
}

close IN2;
close OUT2;
```

慣れないうちは`use warnings`を付ける事をおすすめします。
今回の場合、特に`$line2 =~ undef`の部分について、有用な警告を表示してくれます。

---

#### null文字:

制御文字のひとつで、C言語等においては文字列の終端を表します。文字ですので特定のプログラミング言語によらずCSVの中に紛れる（もしくは意図して挿入する）事があります。

#### 空文字列:

文字がひとつも含まれない文字列を空文字列と言います。制御文字も含みません。

#### undef:

Perlでundefは関数のひとつです。未定義値を返します。定義されていませんので、空文字列ではありません。

Comment: csvファイルにnull文字が存在することはあるのでしょうか？今回のcsvファイルの中にnullが含まれている場合、半角スペースに変換する、というプログラムを作る課題で、perlにはnull文字がないという記事があったり、\0でnull判定ができるとあったり、とりあえず空文字のことだと思って投稿しました。

Comment: 聞く限り、null文字/空文字列/undef の差異で戸惑われているようです。厳密には正しくないですが簡単な説明を追加しました。

Answer (score 2):

`$line2`を調べて置き換えを行っても出力は`@data2`を`join`したものですから意味がありません。
`split`した内容を調べて置き換えをする必要があると思います。
例えば、以下の様にします。

```
my @data2 = split(/,/, $line2);
foreach my $item (@data2){
    if($item eq ""){
        $item = "  ";
    }
}
```

Comment: '0' も unless になってしまうので、たぶんあまり良くないと思います。

Comment: @masm  確かに。 eq で内容が空か調べるように変更しました。「`null` が含まれている」がどういうことかわからない部分があるのでこれでいいかははっきりしませんが、まあ、内容を調べる部分は適宜変更してもらえればいいです。

Answer (score 1):

@data2 は置き換え処理をする前の $line2 から作られているように見えます。順序をすこし変えてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

試していませんが、split & join せずとも置換2回で事足りませんか。
`s/,,/,  ,/g` で置換できないパターンは、`,,,` の2つ目のカンマのようにnullの次でありかつ別のnullの前であるカンマの場合ですので、2回置換で取りこぼしが無くなります。

```
# レコードにnullが含まれている？
if ( $line2 =~ /,,/ ) {
    print "nullがあったよ!\n";
} else {
    print "nullないよ！\n";
}
# nullを半角スペース化
$line2 =~ s/,,/,  ,/g;
$line2 =~ s/,,/,  ,/g;
```